# Alert when a daemon stops writing in log file after some seconds

Tags: linux, inotify, watch

I need to send an alert if one daemon (linux) stops writing in his log file.
This dameon not work properly and it not write any when shutdown.

I am using an inotify for watch this problem.

I see this:

```
inotifywait -e modify -t 10 /usr/local/assp/maillog.txt
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
/usr/local/assp/maillog.txt MODIFY
```

I create this cron:

```
*/1 * * * * inotifywait -e modify -t 120 /usr/local/assp/maillog.txt || echo "Assp stopped" | mail -s "$(hostname) ASSP stopped" mymail@mail.me
```

I think is a bad code. Any better ideas?

Comment: Does the daemon keep running when it stops writing to the log, or does it quit?

Comment: Daemon is up but not work. it's Not work, and not write in log.